# Rearrange by predicate using iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, iterator

In a function with given signature I want to rearrange elements of sequence [first, last) in a such way, that all elements satisfying predicate are placed before ones that don't and return an iterator to a first element that doesn't satisfy given predicate.

My algorithm is

- Start iterating on sequence
- If present element doesn't satisfy predicate replace it with the last one
- Check again if a new element on the same position satisfy it
- If not replace it with (last-1), if yes just proceed further
- Repeat until we reach one of the elements that we have already replaced

My code

```
template<class Iterator, class Predicate>
Iterator Rearrange(Iterator first, Iterator last, Predicate pred) {
  auto res = first;
  if (first == last) {
    ;
  }
  else {
    auto run = first;
    auto end = last;
    auto tmp = *first;
    while (run != end) {
      if (pred(*run) == false) {
      again: tmp = *(--end);
    *end = *run;
    *run = tmp;
    if (pred(*run) == false) {
      goto again;
    }
      }
      ++run;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

it gives me

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::range_error'
  what():  dereferencing end of sequence
Aborted
```

which I can't find and understand. Namely, I can read that somewhere I'm trying to dereference element outside of container, but can't see it in my program. Can anyone help me fix a coding error or improve logic of my algorithm?

Comment: I'd hoped that 18 years ago, when work moved from VB6 to C++ and then C# that I'd never  have to deal with `goto` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input range is non-empty and no element in it satisfies the predicate, your code will be stuck in the `goto` loop and not reach the `while` again. Eventually, `--end` will take `end` before `first`.

If this is a learning exercise, I suggest you get rid of `goto`; you don't want to be learning bad practices and while `goto` can have rare legitimate uses, replacing loops is not one of them. Also, the dance with `tmp` can be replaced with `std::swap`.

If this is not a learning exercise, just use [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) which does exactly what you want.